# shortcut to Today in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

Is there a keyboard shortcut to *Today* (the button circled below) in Outlook 2010?

[image: Today button]

I understand that if you type <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> you'll get there... but that doesn't seem like a shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the quick access toolbar up at the top

[image]

click `more commands` and find the "today" in 'all commands'

[image]

`add` it to the quick access toolbar

Now it will be the nth one in the toolbar.

[image]

If you haven't added other commands, it will be `3`. Now you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The current shortcut seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>T</kbd> for Today, you can try this.